# django - handler404 vs handler500

Tags: python, django

I am now a little bit confused.

There are handler404 and handler500 in Django which I can override. I thought, I can do this:

```
try:
   mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(id=someid)
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
   raise Http404
```

But I would love to know what really caused this 404 - Server Error or just a wrong URL..

how would this be possible? can I have infos about 500 error inside handler404?

in case of 500, handler500 does have a `RequestContext` and things like `{{STATIC_URL}}` will stop workingin 500.html. thats why i thought, i will raise 404 instead and email the admin inside 404 handler about error. does this make sense?

Comment: This question is very confused. Handler404 is for 404 errors, ie not found. 500 is for server errors.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, but ``raise Http404`` gives the same result as some wrong url. my question is, am I doing right by raising 404 even in 500 errors. if so, i would like to have more infos if it is really 404 or 500.

Comment: raise Http404 does the same thing as not found since it's launched when page is not found. Can you give example when you raise error 5xx by yourself? Handler for errors 5xx is used to display page when something goes wrong on server side - at this point django send email to administrators (settings.ADMINS) with details.

Comment: @DimmuR this is the point. I am not raising any 500. instead i am raising only 404. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is this:

In order to generate/cause/raise a 500, you have to request a valid URL.

Its quite simple - the 404 will only be raised if there was no 500 error, because the 500 error would not prevent the link from being valid.

So if its 404, there is no chance for it to also raise a 500; because without you requesting a valid URL, no server side code is run; this thus cannot trigger a 500.

They are mutually exclusive.

In your particular case, here is what happens:

1. You request `/foo/bar/1`
2. This URL is mapped using the url patterns to a view, if it matches - that's it, you have no longer a chance to raise a 404.
3. The request is passed to the handler - now, at this stage, the request pipeline cannot generate a 404.
4. There was an error in your view code - now one of two things can happen:

   1. You anticipate this error with a try/except, and then you can raise whatever
      exception you like. If this exception also returns a response, then whatever
      that response is - that is the error code you are sending back in your reply to the client. So, when you `raise Http404`, it will return a response, with 404 error code.  You can happily return any other response and error code combination.
   2. An error occurs that is not caught by your code, or your code does not return a proper response. In this case, the default exception handler for django will return a response and raise 500. This is the normal/default case.

As you can see from the flow, in any case, to return a 500 response, the URL has to be valid.

Comment: Ok. so in case of 500, my 500.html is just being destroyed. what is the solution for this? I have never seen a 500 page in other websites, is it because their code is perfect or they show 404 instead of showing 500?

Comment: Your `500.html` will only shown if you are running with debug set to false, otherwise the debug handler will run, and that's what shows you the execption trace. So, turn off debug mode, and your 500 error page will show when you (or django) returns a 5xx error code.

Comment: thank you, now I understand how it works. but my question about ``RequestContext - {{STATIC_URL}}`` is however still open. if i turn off the debug, it will show 500.html in server (not in dev), but in 500 case, ``{{STATIC_URL}}`` isnot working. how do I handle this?

Comment: As best practice, you should not make your 500 or 404 pages dependent on your server code - that is, they should work even without the server existing. Some companies host their 500 and 404 pages on Amazon S3 just so even if their server is completely down, at least a response is sent. Bottom line - "hard code" the paths if you must, but make your 500 pages as simple and self-contained as possible.

Comment: ah thank you very much. now I know more about another workround.